# Como fazer um algoritmo de MDC só com soma e subtração?

Tags: algoritmo, matemática

Como faço um algoritmo que calcule o MDC de dois números somente utilizando operações de soma e subtração? É proibido utilizar operadores diferentes dos requisitados.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem operações de comparação, não tem nem como parar o algoritmo, então assumo que se proíbe outras operações aritméticas, não proibindo operações de comparação. Ok?

Para começar, normalmente se utiliza números inteiros positivos, então vou considerar essa condição e em caso de argumentos fora dessas condições deve-se fazer as devidas adaptações.

Segundo, se pudesse usar cálculo de resto de divisão euclidiana (normalmente se usa o símbolo `%`) poderia-se calcular por meio da sequinte recursão: `mdc(a,b)=( b=0 ? a : mdc(b,a%b) )`.

Existe um algoritmo de cálculo de resto de divisão de inteiros positivos que segue a recursão `a%b=( a<b ? a : (a-b)%b )`. Também pode ser implementado sem recursão, assim.

```
resto( a , b )
    enquanto( a>=b )faça
        a <--- a-b
    retorna a
```

Quer dizer que pode-se calcular resto de divisão apenas com loop de subtrações, não utilizando o operador de divisão. Assim, o cálculo de mdc pode trocar a divisão por loop de subtrações.

Com isso, a recursão do mdc se torna `mdc(a,b)=( b=0 ? a : mdc(b,resto(a,b)) )`. Refinando o algoritmo de mdc, ele fica assim.

```
mdc( a , b )
    enquanto( b>0 )faça
        enquanto( a>b )faça
            a <--- a-b
        b <-> a
    retorna( a )
```

Tem alguma dúvida?

Comment: Oi, eu consegui fazer um algoritmo que resolvesse, operadores de comparação são permitidos. Na verdade não consegui simplesmente tomei vergonha abri um livro de cálculo, kkk. Utilizei o algoritmo de Euclides pro cálculo de MDC. Basicamente ele funciona como você descreveu aqui.

Comment: Ok. Que pena que não ajudei. Pode finalizar a pergunta para ela não ficar pendente?

Comment: Imagina, cara, valeu pela ajuda mesmo assim! Eu que sou meio impaciente.